# Android - RecyclerView notifyDatasetChanged not updating layout view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged, recyclerview-layout

I have an Adapter for a `RecyclerView`. The adapter has a property size, that can be either SMALL or LARGE.

Depending on the property, the layouts loaded for viewholders will be different.

I have a button to change this property, however after I set it, and if I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` the views are not updated.

I have also tried `requestLayout` and `invalidate` without success. This is, **`onCreateViewHolder`** is never called again.

Comment: please post the code.

Comment: @htafoya Please share your code so we can help you out. If you are update particular record use notifyitemchanged() instead of notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

notifyDataSetChanged() call onBindViewHolder() when using RecyclerView.It doesnot call onCreateViewHolder.
You can try setAdapter() for the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is like calling

```
recyclerView.setAdapater(new YourCustomRecylcerViewAdapter(yourProperty, listToUpdate))
```

whenever you change the property. This will invoke the **onCreateViewHolder()** of adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it, it was because before `onCreateViewHolder`, `getItemViewType` is called.

If no new view is set then it won't be called. So I had to create a new *viewType* for each of the small views and problem solved :).